# Pagination bug when total pages are 7, it shows an ellipsis instead of page 6

Tags: feature-request, pagination

For example go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.1?tab=newest&pagesize=30, you can see what I mean. (*or check the screenshot below*)

[image]

I know normally it is not a big deal, but Stack Overflow is not a normal website.

**Update**:

- For pages 1, 2, 3 and 4 the issue is it shows an ellipsis (...) instead of #6.
- For pages 5, 6 and 7, it shows an ellipsis instead of #2.

What I'm saying is: There are 7 slots and 7 pages, so no need to use an ellipsis.

[image]

Comment: @Makyen the OP isn’t expecting 6 dots anywhere, just that page 6 is not replaced by dots (elided) when there are only 7 pages.

Comment: In the screenshot page #1 is highlighted, so in page 1 I see 3 dots, it looks the same for 2,3 & 4, for #5, it shows page 6, but it didn't show page 2 and show 3 dots instead

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh... I misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: From a UI POV, given that you don't have infinite space to show page numbers, you have to start eliding page-links at some point. You can either choose to do that with a single algorithm, which just elides how ever many don't fit in the space which you've chosen, and which may be a single page, or you can make some additional special cases such that you don't ever elide only a single page (i.e. you always display one page more than "normal", if that's the only missing page). It might be somewhat better from a UX POV to do that, but it is somewhat more complex.

Comment: I think simple solution would be: do nothing `if pages <= 7` or something similar

Comment: Yes, this would appear to be hard to get right for many sites. Just the other day, I was on a site that showed blue, underlined dots at the end of a text, clickable to read more. When I clicked the "...", it revealed that the remaining text was "it.".

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I'm not saying that's not a reasonable way for it to work. I'm saying that if it does do that is a choice. I'd consider this a feature request, rather than a bug. As a bug, if I were a developer, I'd probably close it as [meta-tag:status-bydesign], because it's working as designed and the designed functionality doesn't cause anything actually incorrect.

Comment: @Makyen yes, it doesn't do anything wrong (it's functionality is correct), but I think is still a bug rather than feature. if I do similar in my projects, I'm sure it reported as a bug by my customers.

Comment: Give it between 6 to 8 weeks) I think this joke perfectly describes the behavior here. Judging from inspecting the markup, the pagination is js-controlled, so adding a code path "if the number of pages equals the number of slots" should be possible to aheive.

Comment: Is the pager broken? No. Can it be improved? Yes. That makes this a [meta-tag:feature-request], not a [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: @Cerbrus - if the *expected result* is to see 7 numbers on a 7-page output, and the *actual result* is 6 numbers + ellipsis, then afaik it is a textbook definition of a bug until confirmed to be "by-design". Anyways, to keep things focused - I stand corrected, it seems like pagination is decided server-side (the page is served like that), which should make the amendment easy enough - the total page count is known in advance.

Comment: @Cerbrus consider this result: `1 ... 2 ... 3 ... 4 ... ... ... 5 ... 6 ... 7 7`, is the pager broken? No, so you saying this is not a bug because somehow pager works?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature! :D

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: that scenario doesn’t happen, so not a valid argument.

Comment: I hate to “pull rank” here, but there have now been 2 _experienced_ meta users (one of’m a moderator, even) that adviced you to change the tag. You’re free to your own opinion, but I strongly advice you to also listen to what other users are saying.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you for your advice, but I am a experienced programmer and this behavior of pagination is clearly a bug to me and not a feature req. actually it is the first time I see your definition about bug. _see my prev comment for an example of working solution that actually is a buggy code_

Comment: _"see my prev comment"_ which illustrates a situation that isn't happening...

Comment: Yes, is not happening on SO, I was answering your comment about bug vs. feature req. you said because pager is not broken, so it is not a bug. I shown you an example about working pager (not broken pager) that has a bug. so your definition is not correct.

Comment: I was talking about this specific case... You wouldn't apply what I say here to NASA, would you? I sure hope not!

Comment: *"but I am a experienced programmer and this behavior of pagination is clearly a bug to me"* - seeing as we're on a site (originally) for professional (and enthusiast) programmers, this has got to be one of the worst bits of reasoning I've seen, very much sounds along the lines of *"I know this is a bug, because it's clearly a bug, you're just inexperienced programmers"* ... I also would not call this a bug and having been programming for more than half my life I'd probably call myself "experienced" as well

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, let's not get personal here. Btw, dug out a nearly [10-year old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85431/odd-behaviour-of-listed-pages-in-paginator) tumbleweeded to obscurity question on the Uber Meta about the same behavior.

Comment: It's 4-1 so far for the "feature request" label. I've rolled back the edit. Mehdi, frankly, it doesn't matter what _you_ think it should be tagged as. If Meta tells you it's the wrong tag for Meta, then it's simply the wrong tag for Meta.